# Wait to send data until all Promises are resolved

Tags: javascript, express, promise, knex.js

I'm trying to query my database twice. I am able to log the data that I want but I am unable to send that data because the promise doesn't resolve in time. I am wondering how I can make it so that I wait till all the promises are resolved before I send the data. Thanks for any help.

```
app.get("/organizations/:slug_id/:category_id", function(req, res, next) {
    queries.getAllProducts(req.params.category_id)
      .then(function(result) {
            return result.map(function(obj) {
                queries.getAllProductsImages(obj.product_id)
                  .then(function(images) {
                        obj["images"] = images;
                        return obj;
                  })
                })
              })
            .then(function(products) {
              res.status(200).json(products)
            })
              .catch(function(error) {
                next(error);
              });
});
```

Comment: That's what `Promise.all` is for

Comment: Return the promise inside the map, and wrap the map into a `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
app.get("/organizations/:slug_id/:category_id", function (req, res, next) {
    queries.getAllProducts(req.params.category_id)
        .then(function (result) {
            return Promise.all(result.map(function (obj) {
                return queries.getAllProductsImages(obj.product_id)
                    .then(function (images) {
                        obj["images"] = images;
                        return obj;
                    });
            }));
        })
        .then(function (products) {
            res.status(200).json(products)
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            next(error);
        });
});
```